# Rose Plant flowering not looking good

Tags: roses

I purchased a rose plant from nearby nursery for pretty cheap with big pot. It had one flower at that time, After 5 days of purchase 3 new flowers bloomed. They were dull and had curled peatals and a smaller size.
This is how the old flower looked when I got it from nursery ( Middle one) The other 3 flowers were about to bloom
[image]

And this is how the new flowers look that bloomed under my care:
[image]

Comment: What is your question?  You have simply shown us two pictures of normal-looking roses.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Chenmunka, I wanted to ask why the flowering is not looking good as the previous flower?

Comment: Do you have a name tag or know the varietal name for the rose?

Comment: @Bamboo It is a English rose, The 2 picture are of the same plant. It rained heavily for few days, Is it overwatered? so The flowering isn't looking good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English rose is not a varietal name I'm afraid, not specific to a variety of rose. However, it seems what you are concerned about is the flower variation in terms of their colour; first, rose flowers only last a few days after they appear (up to 5 or 7 days max for each bloom); second, there is always some small variation in the colour, particularly as your rose has picotee flowers, so you might see some with quite a pronounced deep pink edge to the petals as the flower opens, or you might see some with barely detectable deep pink edges. This is quite normal, but add to that the change that takes place in a bloom as it ages (fading colours, changing structure) then it's possible to have 3 blooms on a rose which opened a day or two after one another and look different from one another. There is nothing you can do to change or fix the colour of the flowers - the ones currently present should be clipped off as their petals start to fall.

I asked about the variety of the rose to try to determine its eventual height and spread; there are few roses which do well in pots after a year or so, they prefer to be in the ground. In terms of fertiliser, assuming you are in the Northern hemisphere, now is not the time to give any; the best way to fertilise roses is to use a specialist Rose Food, which is usually a powder or granular formulation and given twice, once in Spring as new growth gets going, and again 6  weeks later.

With regard to watering, assuming there are drainage holes in the pot, it's next to impossible to over water.

Comment: Thank you so much for this help, but is it normal the that the petals are curled? The flowers gained pink colour at the tips, But the tips are still curled. I am going deadhead them soon. I am in Pakistan, I don't have special soil made for the plant.  The soil is clay like and red coloured, It litreally turns into clay if waterlogged. The pot is placed outside where rain water does fill up the pot, But the soil does drain out a big. It is between Slightly wet and moist soil. Again thank you so much for this help, I don't know the variety but yeah.

Comment: Roses do fine in heavy clay soil in the UK - I know the type of soil you mention, I have seen it before, its not free draining by any means, is it, almost like reddish river clay, but so long as the water can get out the bottom, the rose should cope. The curling petals are usually a sign the flower is 'going over'  meaning its not in the tip top  condition it was when it first opened - its normal.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem isn't your care, but that the roses got older. Roses look about like that when they get older. You can deadhead them to encourage new roses to grow. I might suggest fertilizing, too, if you're not already.

Comment: They just bloomed now, The plant is newly grown from cutting, I think its 1 year old. I didn't fertilize it yet, Is urea good for it?

Comment: Are you saying these aren't the same flowers in both pictures? Urea is just nitrogen; you'll need other stuff, too, if you use that. Something like this might be good: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Miracle-Gro-5-5-lbs-Water-Soluble-Bloom-Booster-Flower-Food-300981005/311954219

Comment: They are the same flowers, I mean why the petals of the flowers that bloomed after 5 days curled and don't have pink colour at the tips? I currently don't have other organic fertilizers right now, Will Urea help the flower as I only have Urea currently.